# Linux Editor to make video for elearning

Tags: editors, video

Does anyone know a solution to create video courses on Linux, i.e:

- recording in the same time the videos from the webcam, the powerpoint / openoffice document, the annotations on the document (using electronic whiteboard) and my speech
- a way to edit after creation to remove / add new video sequences

Answer (score 2):

Try using [RecorditNow](http://recorditnow.sourceforge.net/). Can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) as backends.

Comment: GTKRecordmydesktop (desktop recording software) and Pitivi or Avidemux (programs for video editing).